# Loading a Dynamic Javascript Tree Structure into a JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, dynamic, tree

So I am wanting to read a database, and then form a tree structure and put it in my webpage. I am using the destroydrop tree at the moment, and I can get it to work on its own, but if I want to build the tree and then put it in my webpage, then my page gets overwritten because it uses document.write(tree) to create the tree. I've also tried some other trees which all have the same issue. Anyone know of a tree structure that I can dynamically add to my page without overwriting what is on there? Thanks!

Comment: Overwrites what's there? I don't quite understand. Why not use an existing tree control? Or create a JSP-based custom tag that does the formatting for you? You'll probably need to be more specific with what you want.

Comment: Sorry about that. So I have a page that is loaded. After it is loaded I dynamically build the javascript to create the tree by adding elements to the tree object. The problem is once document.write(tree) is called and I pass it the tree object, it overwrites the webpage and creates a new one with an empty header and I lose all my script references which are needed for the tree to work. I hope that helps a little. =/

Comment: Why would you do a `document.write(...)`? Don't you want to add it to a particular div/span/etc. on the page, and not replace the entire page? Also, use jQuery (or similar) to do the DOM dirty-work. Also, use a tree component, unless you're just building something simple.

Comment: That's exactly what I am wanting to do. I am not allowed to use jQuery or I totally would lol. This is for work, and this tree is quite large. If I load javascript inside a div, will it run it even if the page is loaded?

Comment: You don't load the JavaScript in a div (not that it matters), you build your DOM in JavaScript, and insert that DOM (or HTML) into a div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks much for the help. I ended up just overriding document.write as such

```
document.write = function(){
    document.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML = arguments[0];
}

function getTreeStruct() {
new Ajax.Request('MainServlet', {
    method: 'POST',
    parameters: "action=getTreeStruct",
    onSuccess: function(transport) {

        d = new dTree('d');
        d.add(0, -1, 'Root Element');
        //contains data queried from database to be inserted into the tree.
        var responseArray = transport.responseText.split("|");
        //Add each element to the tree object
        iterate1DArray(function(x) {
            var tempArray = x.split(",");
            if(tempArray[1] != undefined
                    && !(tempArray[0] == 0 && tempArray[1] ==0)){
                d.add(tempArray[0], tempArray[1], tempArray[2]);
            }
        }, responseArray);

        document.write(d);

    }
});

}

function iterate1DArray(func, array) {
    for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        array[i] = func(array[i]);
    }
}
```

I did not include the code for the tree, but it can be found [here](http://destroydrop.com/javascripts/tree/). Just thought I would put this on here in case anyone else has this type of issue. Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [nitobi tree](http://www.nitobi.com/products/completeui/). Nitobi Completeui framework has both client and server sides.

You can find samples in [code repository](https://github.com/nitobi/completeui.git).